# Python group and sum with string as keys

Tags: python, string, sum

Beginners question...
If possible without pandas, I'd like to sum up groups within a list or an array.
Input:

```
Input = [["A",0.2],["B",0.5],["A",0.6],["C",0.1],["B",0.9]]
```

Desired Output:

```
Output = [["A",0.8],["B",1.4],["C",0.1]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you start by getting a piece of paper and pencil and write out the steps you need to do this. Once you have a clear idea in your head, using English or whatever written language you know best, then it will be easier to translate it into python.

Answer (score 2):

You could sum over equal keys by using a dictionary. If you really need, you still can recreate the result to a list of lists via a list comprehension:

```
lst = [["A",0.2],["B",0.5],["A",0.6],["C",0.1],["B",0.9]]

d = dict()
for sl in lst:
    d[sl[0]] = d.get(sl[0], 0) + sl[1]

res = [[k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: the `d.get(sl[0], 0)` is great it simplifies a lot the for loop! +1

Comment: Thanks, works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can by doing this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for arr in input:
    sums[arr[0]] += arr[1]

output = [[key, value] for key,value in sums.items()]
```

This way seems the most idiomatic for me. Following the convention of Python, you should name your variables with lower case and underscore. You can learn more about the defaultdict here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
Dict = {group[0]: 0 for group in Input}
for group in Input: Dict[group[0]] += group[1]
Output = [[group, value] for group, value in Dict.items()]
```

A `dict` can only have unique keys, so we solve half of the problems. To start, each value of each key will be 0.

Next, we iterate through `Input` and add each value to its corresponding key in our `Dict`. So now, our job is almost done.

We only have to convert it to the form you want, using a comprehension list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going for a `dict` as shown hereunder:

```
inp = [["A",0.2],["B",0.5],["A",0.6],["C",0.1],["B",0.9]]

#create an empty dict
out = {}
#for each element of the inp list
for a in inp:
  #if the key does already exist in the dict, you sum the current value
  #with what was found in the array at this iteration 
  if a[0] in out:
    out.update({a[0]:a[1]+out.get(a[0])})
  #you create a new pair (new key, new value) extract from inp
  else:
    out.update({a[0]:a[1]})

print out
#if you really need a nested list as output you can convert back the dict
#into a list of list
res = [[key, val] for key, val in out.items()]
print res
```

**output:**

```
{'A': 0.8, 'C': 0.1, 'B': 1.4}
[['A', 0.8], ['C', 0.1], ['B', 1.4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Output = [ [k,sum(a[1] for a in Input if a[0] == k)] for k in set(a[0] for a in Input) ]
```